# how can i draw bezier curve in openframeworks when i have text file about coordinates

Tags: openframeworks

I want to draw same bezier curve parallelly in `z=0` and `z=1`. I have text file which have coordinates (x and y) about control points of bezier curve. I want to use `decasteljau` algorithm and make the interval `t=0.1` when drawing each curve.

These are the form of text file.

```
p0(x,y) p1(x,y) p2(x,y) p3(x,y)

120 126 114 144 126 157 148 159
148 159 240 164 338 166 446 162
120 126 235 118 337 118 435 123
435 123 462 110 490 115 518 127
518 127 530 132 527 143 519 155
519 155 438 305 307 426 113 504
```

Having eight numbers in each line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `decasteljau` use the `bezierTo` of `ofPolyline` and use curveResolution for your interval requirement.

```
    ofPolyline polyline;

    // First two numbers
    polyline.addVertex(ofPoint(120, 126));

    // Rest of numbers + interval t
    polyline.bezierTo(114, 144, 126, 157, 148, 159, t);

    polyline.draw()
```

> Of course, you first need to [reading the data from a file](https://openframeworks.cc/learning/08_other/readfiletostringvector/) and you might want to normalize and scale your `x` `y` values first. Note that you can give the [`bezierTo`](https://openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofPolyline/#show_bezierTo) 3D coordinates.